# lotusscript method POST with login and password

Tags: post, lotusscript

We've used some code for a long time:

```vb
Xml = |<message xmlns="url">
<login>| & login & |</login>
<password>| & password & |</password>
<body content-type='text/plain'>| & textValue & |</body>
       </message>|
Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
Call objXmlHttp.Open("POST", "url", False)
Call objXmlHttp.Send(Xml)
```

Now they change the url, so we have to use login and password. But I can't understand how I can add password and login in this line `Call objXmlHttp.Open("POST", "url", False)`.

I have an error that can't find msxml3.dll.

Maybe someone knows how to solve the problem?

Add information:
I have to have JSON post.
Type of JSON

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://their_site'
\ --header 'Authorization: Basic
Code111'
\ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{
...some inf...
"contentType": "text/plain",
"content": "Hello World!"
}
```

Comment: We can't really help you unless you tell us what format the site is requiring for passing the  login name and password.

Comment: name/api/contents. they've used another url without password and login. But then they decided to change access

Answer (score 1):

Passing the username and password directly in the URL is not secure, so it is not surprising the site you are trying to connect to is not supporting that anymore.
You need to find out what kind of authorization the site is using, and modify your code to match that. I suspect they are using basic authorization, then you need to base64 encode the credentials and pass them in the header of your call.

Comment: their answer "json by POST method". 
now I can't understand, can I use this code or I have to change all ? I need to change their example "curl --location --request POST 'http://their_url'
\ --header 'Authorization: Basic
Code123'
\ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{
"source": "name",
....
"contentType": "text/plain",
"content": "Hello World!"
}
" 
I need to apply their example in my code
can i use it in objXmlHttp.Open ("POST"...?

Comment: You need to rewrite your code. The payload has to be formatted as JSON (not XML). You still make an HTTP POST call, like you do now, but you need to add some headers in the call. Since they use basic authorization, you need to concatenate the username and password (with a colon separating them), then base64 encode the resulting string and put in the header. 
I would also suggest that you use ServerXMLHTTP instead of XMLHTTP, and also to use MSXML 3.0 or later:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762278(v=vs.85)

Comment: If you are using Notes/Domino 10 or later, you can use the native NotesHTTP Request class:
https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_NOTES_HTTPREQUEST_CLASS.html

Comment: I use 9Notes, so Dim webRequest As NotesHTTPRequest - Class or type name not found

Comment: Of course, I said that is a new function that came in Notes 10.  Did you updte your code to set the headers as Richard suggested in the other response?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) for an explanation of how the Authorization: header must be formatted. Briefly, you concatenate the username, a colon character, and the password, and you base64 encode them. Then you put that base64 string after the "Authorization:" header in the post.

And you will no longer be sending actual XML. You can still use obxXmlHttp, but you will have to change your `Xml =` assignment to conform to the JSON format that they are requiring.

Comment: xml=|http://their_site?login:my_login&password:my_password|  So I have to use code like this?

Comment: but I can't understand how can I add other parameters: xml=|http://their_site?login:my_login&password:my_password|

xml2=|'http://their_site?login:my_login&password:my_password'
{ ....
"contentType": "text/plain",
"content": "Hello World!"
}
|
 Call objXmlHttp.open("POST",xml, False)
 Call objXmlHttp.Send(xml2)

Comment: If your objXmlHttp variable is based on the xmlHttpRequest class, you will need to use the setRequestHeader method to set the value of the "Authorization" header. You will need to write (or find) some code to the base64 encoding, too.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader